# How to Design Optimal Database Design to Handle Subscription And Its Usage

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, subscriptions

What would be a optimal solution to design database to handle Subscriptions

E.g
I have subscription plans which consists of :

- Price
- Validity : e.g 6 months, 1 Month
- Credits : E.g 100, 1 Credit/Booking

**How to track the usage and maintain history of the user's subscriptions. 

Manage Renewals / Expire Plans**

Answer (score 3):

You should have the following tables

1. Customers
2. Subscriptions
3. Price plans (references subscription)
4. Price plan line items (references price plan)
5. Customersubscriptions (references customers and subscription)
6. CustomerSubscriptionHistory
7. Credit types
8. CustomerCredits (references customer & credit types)
9. CustomerCreditHistory
10. Invoice ( reference customer)
11. PaymentTypes (cash, card, bitcoins etc...)
12. PaymentHistory  (can track failure & success in 1 table)

I have listed the entities based on my understanding, HTH

Comment: In Which table I should track he usage of the credits. like Subtracting the total credits.

Comment: You will have records in `CustomerCredits` with +ve and -ve values which you can sum up during generating the invoice